# Can't receive XML in controller's argument

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

## I want to receive in controller XML object, but I always get null object.

It looks like that
XmlDataContractSerializer**Output**Formatter() **works** because I can output XML in other case but XmlDataContractSerializer**Input**Formatter()) **doesn't work**;

I tried to use 
**setupAction.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()**
or pass argument to
setupAction.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter(**setupAction**)

but nothing works

```
services.AddMvc(setupAction =>
            {
                setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
                setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
                setupAction.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter());
            });
```

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateAuthor([FromBody] AuthorForCreationDto author)
        {
            if (author is null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
...
}
```

```
public class AuthorForCreationDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BookForCreationDto> Books { get; set; }
        = new List<BookForCreationDto>();
    }
```

**XML**

```
<AuthorForCreationDto xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Library.API.Models">
        <DateOfBirth xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
            <d3p1:DateTime>1948-03-03T00:00:00Z</d3p1:DateTime>
            <d3p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d3p1:OffsetMinutes>
        </DateOfBirth>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <Genre>Thriller</Genre>
        <LastName>Ellroy</LastName>
</AuthorForCreationDto>
```

***In postman I set Content-Type application/xml and Accept application/json***

Comment: Try putting ValidateInput(false) on top of the controller.

Comment: I added it but I needed to install ASP.NET.MVC dependencie but event that it still doesn't work